# Why do we use explicit data types? (from a low level point of view)

Tags: c, types, x86, language-design, low-level

When we take a look at some fundamental data types, such as char and int, we know that a char is simply an unsigned byte (depending on the language), int is just a signed dword, bool is just a char that can only be 1 or 0, etc. My question is, why do we use these types in compiled languages instead of just declaring a variable of type byte, dword, etc, since the operations applied to the types mentionned above are pretty much all the same, once you differentiate signed and unsigned data, and floating point data?

To extend the context of the question, in the C language, if and while statements can take a boolean value as an input, which is usually stored as a char, which exausts the need for an explicit boolean type.

In practice, the 2 pieces of code should be equivilant at the binary level:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    char y = 'c';
    printf("%d %c\n", x - 8, y + 1);
    return 0;
}

//outputs: -3 d
```

-

```
signed dword main()
{
    signed dword x = 5;
    byte y = 'c';
    printf("%d %c\n", x - 8, y + 1);
    return 0;
}

//outputs: -3 d
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dword"?

Comment: double word; 4 bytes of space

Comment: So you mean specifically an x86 double-word, not MIPS or PowerPC (where a word is 32 bits).  Tagging x86 then.

Comment: Well, [the second system C ran on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeywell_6000_series#CPU) had 36-bit words, so a "double word" would be 72 bits wide.

Comment: If `x` were only declared as a `dword`, how would you or the compiler know whether it is an `int`, an `unsigned int`, a `float`, a pointer to `struct foo`, or some other pointer? For the code `x - 8`, should the compiler load `x`, an integer 8, and do an integer subtract, or should it load `x`, a floating-point 8, and do a floating-point subtract?

Comment: A byte is not always 8 bits, on octal systems 9 bits feels much better with a 36 bit word and as pointed out a 72 bit double word.  x86 has become an also ran, for every x86 you have you have a handful to dozens of non-x86 either in the same box or elsewhere in your life.  And a number of those an int is 32 bits or 16 bits and called a word.  but that is exactly why we have such things in the language so that different compiler implementations can choose a size favorable to them.  on the popular x86 compilers the size of an int changed at least once over time.

Comment: a bool being a char wouldnt be optimal for most systems it can take more program space to deal with 8 bit items rather than a native size like 32 or 64 bits.  So no reason to assume a bool is 8 bits.  a bool is true or false the size is determined by the specific compilers implementation.

Comment: because you dont need to use a boolean type to represent true or false operations in C no you dont need to use that type.  you can use any of the types that make sense (and probably ones that dont).

Comment: the C standard itself is not free, can be had for a reasonable price, but there are review drafts that are available for free.  The answers to your questions are there, and/or at least the corrections to your assumptions.

Comment: you are also assuming that the same compiler same development machine version of everything is used in order to make that comparision that they are equal at the "binary" level.

Comment: also a char is not assumed to be signed nor unsigned I believe that the default is up to the compiler implementation and not the standard.  that may have changed over time.  that is at least why there is an unsigned char and a char just like there is an unsigned int and an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A programming language defines an "abstract" data model, that a computer designer is free to implement his way. For instance, nothing mandates to store a Boolean in a byte, it could be "packed" as a single bit along with others. And if you read carefully the C standard, you will notice that a char has no defined size.

[Anecdotically, I recall an old time when FORTRAN variables, including integers, floats but also booleans, were stored on 72 bits on IBM machines.]

Language designers should put little constraints on machine architecture, to leave opportunities for nice designs. In fact, languages have no "low level", they implicitly describe a virtual machine not tied to a particular hardware (it could be implemented with cogwheels and ropes).

As far as I know, only the ADA language went to the point of specifying in details all the characteristics of the arithmetic, but not to the point of enforcing a number of bits per word.

---

Ignoring the boolean type was one of the saddest design decision in the C language. I took as late as C99 to integrate it :-(

Another sad decision is to have stopped considering the int type as the one that naturally fits in a machine word (and should have become 64 bits in current PCs).

Comment: Why would you want an array of `int` to waste twice as much memory bandwidth / cache footprint on a 64-bit CPU?  And require more machine-code bytes for REX prefixes on x86-64.  Being as wide as a register is more common for `long`.  Your program can't depend on `int` being any wider than 16 bits if you want to write fully portable code, so there's little benefit to making it super-wide on some targets.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I should have said "could" rather than "should". (By the way, one might ponder the usefulness of increasing the register and ALU width  to 64 bits, mostly for the sake of enlarging the address space). The decision to define the int size belongs to the implementor. If 32 bits is considered efficient, then 32 bits. But with int becoming de facto 32 bits, the initial intent was lost.

Comment: We definitely want 64-bit numbers for timestamps and various other things, not *just* for pointer calculations.  And extended-precision integers in 64-bit chunks are twice as efficient as 32-bit chunks.  So there are many cases where 64-bit registers / ALU are useful.  But 32-bit is still big enough for your average loop counter or whatever, and 32 bits is still the natural most efficient size on most 64-bit machines (e.g. x86-64 for code-size) or just as efficient outside of cache footprint issues.  Computers have grown relative to typical sizes of computer programs since the 70's.

Comment: @PeterCordes: all of this is negotiable.

Comment: I'm just responding to your claim that it's "sad" that `int` doesn't fill a register on 64-bit machines.  32-bits is "big enough" for everything that it makes sense to use `int` for.  Wildly varying type sizes doesn't help anyone use a size that's big enough, but not so big that it wastes memory that isn't needed.  If you had a 64-bit ISA that couldn't truncate `add`/`sub`/`mul` results to 32-bit for free, you'd presumably make `int` 64-bit on that target, but all 64-bit ISAs (even Alpha, which was designed from the ground up as a 64-bit ISA, not an extension to a 32-bit ISA) do have that.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I said negotiable. I didn't say I wanted to enter the negotiation.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, why do we use these types in compiled languages

To make the code target-agnostic.  Some platforms only have efficient 16-bit integers, and forcing your variables to always be 32-bit would make your code slower for no reason when compiled for such platforms.  Or maybe you have a target with 36-bit integers, and a strict 32-bit type would require extra instructions to implement.

Your question sounds very x86-centric.  x86 is not the only architecture, and for most languages not the one language designers had in mind.

Even more recent languages that were designed in the era of x86 being widespread on desktops and servers were designed to be portable to other ISAs, like 8-bit AVR where a 32-bit `int` would take 4 registers vs. 2 for a 16-bit `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a high-level language is to provide some isolation from machine details.  So, we speak of "integers", not some particular number of bytes of memory.  The implementation then maps the higher-level types on whatever seems best suited to the target hardware.

And there are different semantics associated with different 4-byte types: for integers, signed versus unsigned is important to some classes of programs.

I understand this is a C question and it's arguable about how high-level C is or is not; but it is at least intended to be portable across machine architectures.

And, in your example, you assume 'int' is 32 bits. Nothing in the language says that has to be true.  It has not always been true, and certainly was not true in the original PDP-11 implementation. And nowadays, for example, it is possibly appropriate to have 'int' be 64 bits on a 64-bit machine.

Note that it's not invariable that languages have types like "integer", etc. BLISS, a language at the same conceptual level as C, has the machine word as the only builtin datatype.